# having vim remap names just visually

Tags: vim

Is there a way I can get vim to reword a variable name like `izpxh` into something like `isEnabled` when I actually find out what it contains (and build a dict out of it), but without actually changing the contents of the file ? Like, if I am in browsing mode, I get the remapped texts. When I go in insert mode, the line I am at shows the original text, and I see the real variable names. When I exit insert mode, the remap is applied so I visually see proper remapped names. Of course, when I save, I want the original names, not the remapped ones.

Briefly, does vim ship with Fortran77 sanity goggles ?

Comment: If only `conceal` supported more than single chars... :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a function, `MakeFortranSane` that uses `:%s/\<izpxh\>/isEnabled/g` et al. to replace the Fortran rubbish with readable stuff.
2. Write a function, `MakeInsane`, that does the opposite.
3. Apply these statements:

   ```
   augroup fortransanity
       au!
       au BufRead,InsertLeave,BufWritePost * call MakeFortranSane()
       au InsertEnter,BufWritePre * call MakeInsane()
   augroup END

   doautocmd fortransanity FileType fortran
   ```

You could also get more fine-grained and pass `getline('.')` as an argument to the functions on `InsertLeave` and `InsertEnter` so the translation only happens on that line.

Comment: I would suggest `*` in pattern and `if &ft is# 'fortran' | call Make...() | endif`.

Comment: Good idea, ZyX.  In fact, I think there might be an even better way with `augroup`s.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried updated answer? I have not, but it seems like it is not going to work: as far as I know, it should setup autocommands for all files and run FileType event(s) defined in group fortransanity... if they were defined, of course.

Comment: Another idea is to call a function on `FileType` event with pattern `*` that, depending on filetype, will either set up these events for current buffer only (`<buffer>` in place of pattern, see `:h autocmd-buffer-local`), or use `autocmd! fortransanity * <buffer>` to clear all autocommands related to current buffer (it is for the case when vim filetype detection was wrong and user has manually set different filetype after file was detected as containing a fortran source code).